# Using .htaccess to restrict access to files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, restriction

I have 2 domains hosted on the same account but I want to restrict the second one to not access files.

I have abc123.com and zyx987.com.

In my php I do everything I need to display the domain name and template based on the domain but I want only the /download files to be accessed from abc123.com.

The download folder has files like: file1.pdf or file2.zip.

I tried the 'deny from all' but this didnt work since the other domain is blocked too.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what you have to do. Put this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?zyx987.com$
RewriteRule ^download - [F]
```

This will block any request like:

```
/download/
/download/file1.jpg
/download/another/file.zip
```

and give a permission denied.